# Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document', wrong xpath expression

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have calendar and I want to pick a proper day, test will be executed everyday and I have method which takes today's date.

I have WebElement pickDay which should find wanted day, the HTML code is:

```
<td class="class" <data-hanlder="selectDay" data-month="5" data-year="2018">
<a class="classX">5</a>
</td>
```

and xPath expression is (for example):

```
String whichMonth = "5"
String whichDay = "5"
day = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@text(),"+whichDay+") AND (@data-month,"+whichMonth+")]"));
```

But intellij keeps telling me:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contains(@text(),5) AND (@data-month,5)]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

And I dont really know what the problem is with this expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) text() is a function, not an argument. @ not needed here

2) don't use contains() for month to avoid mess (1, 10, 11, 12 for example)

Try the following one:

```
//*[@data-month="+whichMonth+"]/a[text()="+whichDay+"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following, because it looks like there is missing apostrophes in your xpath :

```
day = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'"+whichDay+"') AND (@data-month,'"+whichMonth+"')]"));
```